# How to include all bibliography in a specific slide in rmarkdown to beamer pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, beamer, bibtex

I am using a `.Rmd` file to generate a beamer PDF presentation (which, therefore, accepts `LaTeX` code).

In the standard `R Markdown`, the reference goes into the last slide. But I want to specify it in a general slide (or specifically, before the last slide).

This is what I have tried so far:

````
---
title: "Multivariate Regression Model for Count Data"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
        in_header: /home/guilherme/GoogleDrive/Analises/Modelo/extra_settings_2.tex
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
bibliography: /home/guilherme/GoogleDrive/Analises/Modelo/referencias_so.bib
csl: /home/guilherme/GoogleDrive/Analises/Modelo/stilo_biblio_so.csl
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

## Ref

[@tmb]
[@r]
[@glmmTMB]
[@compoisson]

## Bibliography
\vspace{.5mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\tiny
\printbibliography
\vspace{.5mm}

##

\huge 
+ Thank you for your atention.
````

Content of `extra_settings_2.tex`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/guilherme/GoogleDrive/Analises/Modelo/referencias.bib}
```

[Link for `csl`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CP2mv4tBqt3EGgInMM45ZUR73CRVs1zV/view?usp=sharing) and [`Bib` files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kwvltMiTYpr8CYia2o4USYw17OSTpruV/view?usp=sharing):

What happens is this:

[image]

What I need:

1. References appear before the last slide.
2. Font size small, so that the reference will fit in only one frame.
3. The `.csl` reference style still applies to my documment.

I am using [Tinytex, which is based on TeX Live](https://yihui.org/tinytex/)

It shows me an error after compilation (that I don't know how to handle):

```
Output created: teste_pres.pdf
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 118.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                teste_pres
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that works without extra files we don't have access to?

Comment: Included link files on the question. The main point is to able to place the full list of used References in a certain frame (not the last one) from R Markdown to PDF. Thank you

Comment: I managed changing the reference slide position by changing the last two frames:
## Reference {.allowframebreaks}
\vspace{.5mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\tiny
\vspace{.5mm}

<div id="refs"></div>

##

\huge 
+ Thank you for your atention.

(comment now:) However, it still asks to (re)run Biber on the file (and then, LaTeX afterwards)